# Google adsense images in some of the ads not getting displayed on my website

Tags: adsense, google-ad-manager

Google adsense images in some of the ads not getting displayed on my website https://www.mypleaks.com even after iframe have rendered correctly. The empty slot mentioned in the below screenshot can be seen on the website. On inspecting these empty slots, it can be seen ads have rendered but the image didn't display.[image]

Anyone has idea how to fix this issue..?

Comment: Can you check whether `aswift_0` iframe is empty? It's possible that empty ad response was returned and `adsbygoogle.js` decided not to collapse empty slot as it might cause reflow given that ad location is already in view.

Comment: No its not empty. Sorry for late reply. Will you please have a in the website https://www.mypleaks.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link about [troubleshooting your ads](https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/9502771?visit_id=637324005631984534-2713300339&rd=3).

There could be a issue with [invalid traffic](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/16737?hl=en&ref_topic=1348566) as well, as the adds are indistinguishable from each other on some pages. This should do the trick.

Comment: I tried troubleshooting, but it didn't work. Actually its strange, On firfox all the ads are visible but not on the chrome. So not sure what causing this problem on chrome.